# Get comma between multiple reference superscript numbers

Tags: cross-referencing, punctuation, superscripts

When I add multiple references at the same point in my document, the superscript numbers are shown directly next to each other. I want a comma between them but cannot work out how to do that.

```
It was a sunny day on the 14th of July.\cite{reference1}\cite{reference2}
```

This appears as

It was a sunny day on the 14ht of July.12 (12 are superscript numbers)

How can I make it,

It was a sunny day on the 14ht of July.1,2

Comment: Did you try `\cite{reference1, reference2}`

Comment: I'll post an answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\cite{reference1,reference2}` should do the trick